# I tried to search but I couldn't get it right with Parse error

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I real need a help with this error. It keep me all night awake try to figure out to might be the problem but I can't get it right.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function_construction'
>   (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amimo\includes\database.php on line 6

This is my code:

```php
<?php

function strip_zeros_from_date($marked_string = "") {
    // first remove the marked zeros
    $no_zeros = str_replace('*'), '', $no_zeros);
    $cleaned_string = str_replace('*0', '' , $no_zeros);
    return $cleaned_string;
}

function redirect_to($location = NULL) {
    if ($location!: = NULL) {
        header("location :{$location}");
        exit;
    }
}

function out_message($message = "") {
    if (! empty($message)) {
        return "<p class=\"message\">{$message}</p>";
    } else {
        return"";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please add full code of your `database.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

you have problem in this line-

```
$no_zeros =str_replace('*'),'' , $no_zeros);
```

it should be

```
 $no_zeros =str_replace('*','' , $no_zeros);
```

also in this line

```
if($location!: = NULL){
```

should be

```
if($location != NULL){
```

also in this line

```
return"<p class=\"message\">{$message} </p>";
```

it should be

```
return  "<p class=\"message\">{$message} </p>";
```

also in this line

```
return"";
```

it should be

```
return "";
```

Comment: please add comments what is removed or what is added to each line. It will help every-one

Comment: @Paul Crovella thank you for your info bro